# How to filter issues with specific priority in jira rest API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I am using JIRA `GET /rest/api/3/search` And I want to filter issues by their priority, but using this URL does not work. `https://MyJira.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search??jql=priority="Low"` I am really new, so sorry if my question is very basic.
I tried different filters but it is returning all the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there; just use "Low" without quotes:

```
https://myjira.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/search?jql=priority=Low
```

And as additional resource on Priority field and all other JQL operators&fields, you can check [this Atlassian documentation page](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/advanced-search-reference-jql-fields/#Priority).